# What RegistryValue Root should be used in case of Single Package Authoring installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

What RegistryValue Root should be used in case of Single Package Authoring installation?
This is a simple Single Package Authoring installation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Product Name='Foobar 1.0' Id='GUID' UpgradeCode='GUID'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'>

    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installer"
      Comments='Foobar is a registered trademark of Acme Ltd.' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'
      InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes" Value="2" />
    <Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Secure="yes" Value="1" />
    <Property Id='ApplicationFolderName' Value="Acme" />
    <Property Id='WixAppFolder' Value="WixPerUserFolder" />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
    <Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installation [1]" />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='Acme' Name='Acme'>
          <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Foobar 1.0'>

            <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='GUID'>
              <File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' DiskId='1' Source='FoobarAppl10.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
                <Shortcut Id="startmenuFoobar10" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="Foobar10.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
              </File>
            </Component>

          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0">
          <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="GUID">
            <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id='Complete' Title='Foobar 1.0' Description='The complete package.'
      Display='expand' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR'>
      <Feature Id='MainProgram' Title='Program' Description='The main executable.' Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
        <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
      </Feature>
    </Feature>

    <Icon Id="Foobar10.exe" SourceFile="FoobarAppl10.exe" />

    <UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_MySetup" />
    </UI>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

During installation registry key 'Software[Manufacturer][ProductName]' will be created under HKCU root.
It is correct in case of per user installation.
But I am not sure that it is correct in case of per machine installation.
It is impossible to use HKLM instead of HKCU - wix will not compile such a file.
There is the error "ICE38: Component ProgramMenuDir installs to user profile. It's KeyPath registry key must fall under HKCU" during compilation.
Is it a problem?
Or should I use HKCU in case of per user and per machine installations if I use Single Package Authoring installation?

Comment: Have you tried HKMU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer XML uses the root type "HKMU" to the MSI type "(none)" (-1).  See: [Registry Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168(v=vs.85).aspx)

> (none) - 0x001 -1 If this is a per-user installation, the registry
>   value is written under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  If this is a per-machine
>   installation, the registry value is written under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
>   Note that a per-machine installation is specified by setting the
>   ALLUSERS property to 1.